# ios avplayer can't read data from proxy

Tags: ios, audio, proxy, avplayer

i used AVPlayer to play a audio file that exists in the QA server. i must use a proxy to access this server, however. The question is i can read any from this proxy. i'm sure the proxy is right, because the image read from the proxy displayed correctly.And if the url is not in the QA server, the AVPlayer can play it correctly. anybody has the same problem?

Comment: how about the avplayer? its goes well or can't play anything? if can't maybe you can check the system hosts file, bind the ip address to the QA server